# TypeError: argument of type 'ValueError' is not iterable in qpsolvers in python

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am new to python optimization using `qpsolvers` and I have problem with running the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from qpsolvers import solve_qp

P = np.array([4.,5.,5.,8.]).reshape(2,2)
q = np.array([-3.,2.]).reshape(1,2)[0]
G = np.array([1,1,-2,-3,1,0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1]).reshape(6,2)
h = np.array([2400.,-1100.,1200.,1500.,-300.,0.])
A = None
b = None

sol = solve_qp(P,q,G,h,A,b,solver='quadprog')
```

I got this error:

```
sol = solve_qp(P,q,G,h,A,b,solver='quadprog')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qpsolvers/__init__.py", line 262, in solve_qp
    return quadprog_solve_qp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qpsolvers/quadprog_.py", line 90, in quadprog_solve_qp
    if "matrix G is not positive definite" in e:
TypeError: argument of type 'ValueError' is not iterable
```

I am really not sure what cause the problem. Any help for this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think this is an issue both with the `qpsolvers` code and your example.

The `qpsolvers` error is that it has `if "matrix G is not positive definite" in e:` instead of `if "matrix G is not positive definite" in str(e):`.

If you correct this then the error `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'double' but got 'long'` remains. This is because all of you inputs are floats apart from `G`. If you replace it with `G = np.array([1., 1., -2., 3., 1., 0., 0., 1., -1.,  0., 0., -1.]).reshape(6,2)` then I think this should resolve your issue.

Comment: The exception handling code has been fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Maddo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64848862/3721564) is right, if you replace the last line of your code by

```py
sol = solve_qp(P, q, G.astype(float), h, A, b, solver="quadprog")
```

then it will properly return `sol == array([300., 166.66666667])`.